# como puedo obtener la función obtiene el mayor

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo resolver el ejercicio con el flujo de control `if`?

```
function obtenerMayor(x, y){
  // ...
}
```

El ejercicio me indica que `(x, y)` son números enteros y que devuelva el mas grande y si son iguales que devuelva cualquiera de los dos.

Esto es lo que pensaba que podía hacer:

```
var mayor =math.max (x,y);
  document.write(mayor)
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140479/discussion-on-question-by-xrexdlc-como-puedo-obtener-la-funcion-obtiene-el-mayor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta es la solución que estás buscando, esta es una forma de resolver, por supuesto existen muchas más formas y más sencillas de resolver como por ejemplo con un math.max()

```html
function obtenerMayor(x, y) {
    if(typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') {
      if(x > y){
        return x
      }else if(y > x) {
        return y
      }else if(x === y){
        return x
      }
    }else return 'ambos valores tienen que ser numeros'
  }
```

Comment: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 10
    Received: undefined

      21 | describe('obtenerMayor(x, y)', function() {
      22 |   it('should return x if it is larger than y', function() {
    > 23 |     expect(obtenerMayor(10, 5)).toBe(10);
         |                                 ^
      24 |   });
      25 |   it('should return y if it is larger than x', function() {
      26 |     expect(obtenerMayor(50, 100)).toBe(100);

      at Object.<anonymous> (03-JS-II/homework/tests/JSII.test.js:23:33)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma, en donde evalúas si los dos parámetros que recibe la función son mayores, menores o iguales:

```js
function obtenerMayor(x, y) {
  if (x > y) {
    console.log(x + ' es mayor que ' + y);
  } else if (x < y) {
    console.log(x + ' es menor que ' + y);
  } else if (x === y){
    console.log(x + ' es igual a ' + y);
  }
}

obtenerMayor(5, 10);
obtenerMayor(10, 5);
obtenerMayor(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Otra opción**: Muestra solo cual es el número MAYOR y si los 2 son iguales puede devolver o `x` o `y`

```js
  function obtenerMayor(x, y) {
      if (x > y) {
        console.log(`NUMERO MAYOR: ${x}`); //Sintaxis con template literals
      } else if(x === y) {
        console.log(`NUMERO: ${x}`);//Sintaxis con templates literals
      }else{
        console.log(`NUMERO MAYOR: ${y}`);
      }
    }
    obtenerMayor(10, 5);
```